# Replacing Do loop by some other method

Tags: list-manipulation

How would you solve this example in mathematica?

Each 5 steps `y` should be doubled starting from 300.

```
ystart = 300;
n = 1;

Do[
 If[Mod[x, 5] == 0, y = ystart*n; n = n*2];
 Print[x + 1, " ", y]
 , {x, 0, 100}
 ]

1 300
...
5 300

6 600
...
10 600
...
11 1200
...
15 1200
...
```

Comment: It depends on what's going on for those 5 iterations when `y` isn't doubling. But `y = 300; t = 1; Do[Do[Print["t = " <> ToString[t++] <> ", y = " <> ToString[y]], 5]; y *= 2, 3]` should do something like what you're after.

Comment: What if you use `{x,0,100,5}`? Then you don't need the `If`.

Answer (score 4):

Procedural programming in *Mathematica* is messy and error prone. This is an iterated function system, so express the transformation as a function and iterate:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + 1, 2 y} /; Mod[x, 5] == 0
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + 1, y}
```

Two cases here: the special case `Mod[x, 5] == 0` and the general case for everything else.

Since you want the result of each iteration, `NestList` is the appropriate tool. Use `MatrixForm` to format the result.

```
NestList[f, {1, 300}, 100] // MatrixForm
(* Nicely formatted, long output *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner that makes sure that we're always dealing with packed arrays of integer (unless we go above max machine integer, of course):

```
n=274;
ConstantArray[150, {Quotient[n, 5] + 1, 5}]*2^Range[Quotient[n, 5] + 1] // 
  Flatten // Transpose[{Range[n], #[[;;n]]}] &
```

`n` is of course the desired number of elements. `n=274` happens to be the maximum `n` before an integer larger than `2^63-1` is generated in the intermediate calculations and the arrays have to be unpacked to use bignums.

Comment: `Floor[n/5]` is better done as `Quotient[n, 5]`.

Comment: @J.M. avoids generating an intermediate `Rational`, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, and can be faster for large enough `n` since you avoid computing a GCD in generating the `Rational[]` result.

Comment: @J.M. this revision should be more or less optimal, I think. Though for large enough `n` the value `2^n` will be far beyond max machine integer.

Comment: Yeah, your solution was already pretty good (IOU a +1), so my nudge about `Quotient[]` was only but a further improvement. :)

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, in fact `n=300` will already not give a packed array, the limit is around  `n=275` (but since the result for `n=276..280` is given in the intermediate calculations, we're capped at 274 in this implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to compute values of `x` and `y` that match a step pattern at a given interval. To begin, we need a generating function that gives `y` values for each interval. Here, the `x` interval is 5, and the starting `y` value is 300. `FindSequenceFunction`finds a function that generates the sequence.

```
FindSequenceFunction[{{1, 300}, {6, 600}, {11, 1200}, {16, 2400}}, i]
```

> ```
> 75*2^(1 + (4 + i)/5)
> ```

This function results in a sequence of `y` values for each value of `i`, where `y` doubles at each interval of 5 steps. For example:

```
(75*2^(1 + (4 + i)/5)) /. i -> Range[1, 30, 5]
```

> ```
> {300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600}
> ```

We can use `FindSequenceFunction` to create a generating function using arbitrary values to begin at `ystart`, with `interval` for `x`, and `base` for multiplier (`base = 2` doubles the `y` values). Note: `ystart` and `base` must be non-zero integers, `interval` must be a positive integer. Using the values from the question, we have:

```
ystart = 300;
interval = 5;
base = 2;
g[i_] := FindSequenceFunction[{{1, ystart*base^0}, {interval + 1, 
    ystart*base^1}, {2 interval + 1, ystart*base^2}, {3 interval + 1, 
    ystart*base^3}}, i]
```

Use `g[i]` to create values of `x` and `y` for `x` from 1 to a number of steps.

```
steps = 100;
TableForm[values = Thread[{
    Range[1, steps],
    Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[#, interval] & /@
        (g[i] /. i -> Range[1, steps, interval])], steps]}
]]
```

> ```
> 1     300
>   ...
> 5     300
> 6     600
>  ...
> 10    600
> 11    1200
>  ...
> 96    157286400
>  ...
> 100   157286400
> ```

Display `values` by rows:

```
Print[ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2]] & @@@ values;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the single value at the end of the list is not wanted, this works:

```
ystart = 300;
Flatten[ NestList[2 # &, ConstantArray[#, 5], 100/5-1] /. # -> ystart ]
```

A list of {sequence number,value} pairs is given by

```
Transpose[{Range[1, 100], Flatten[NestList[2#&, ConstantArray[#,5], 100/5-1] /. # -> ystart]}]
```